# Magento 2: Website not working after enable Full page cache?

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I am using Magento 2.1.1, When i enabled all caches excepts `Full page caching` then my site front-end is working fine but when I enabled `Full page caching` and refresh all cache also then front-end is not working.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue and how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

After enable error reporting, I am getting issue with one extension only.

**ERROR:** `Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdentities() on null in /home/salusdcw/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 373`

Comment: @BoronCoder have you tried with deleting `var/generation` , `var/cache`, `var/page_cache` folder ? and then check ?

Comment: @ManthanDave yes, i delete complete var/* but still getting same issue.

Comment: run `setup:di:compile`  and chek is  there any error shows or not ? also after that run `setup:static-content:deploy` command

Comment: Ok , let me check

Comment: @ManthanDave , After run `setup:di:compile` it's not showing any error in terminal and i completed the static content also but still facing same issue.

Comment: So by disabling that module all works fine? It's paid/free plugin?

Comment: @AnkitShah I am using quickview extension (FREE) and after disable that extension everything is working fine.

Comment: Use this if not using http://www.weltpixel.com/advance-product-quick-view.html

Comment: @AnkitShah  Now i added lot of functionality based on popup of my current extension. I can't revert back with new extension. Do you know why this error is comin `Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdentities() on null in /home/salusdcw/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 373`